# Kendo Dialog Action with <form> Tag

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

I have some confused with kendo. Hope everybody help me.

```
    $("#dialog").kendoDialog({
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        title: "Check Information",
        visible: false,
        actions: [
            { text: 'NO' },
            { text: 'OK', primary: true, action: onSubmit},
        ]
    }).data("kendoDialog");

    $("#openButton").click(function(){
    var dialog = $("#dialog").data("kendoDialog");
    dialog.open();
    });
```

On top is Kendo code, and this form will submit after check validator. My ideas is "Open dialog, I want click "OK" call action: onSubmit then implementation method of $("form").
But when I click button submit form (#openButton). It just opened a dialog and it also submitted $("form").submit(function(event)." Can everybody help me how to fix it.

```
    function onSubmit(e) {
        $("form").submit(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            if (validator.validate()) {
                validationSummary.html("<div class='k-messagebox k-messagebox-success'>Hooray! Your tickets has been sent!!!</div>");
            }
            else {
                validationSummary.html("<div class='k-messagebox k-messagebox-error'>Oops! There is invalid data in the form.</div>");
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dialog is a window that is opened programmatically.  The way I do it, if the form is submitted, open the dialog, then let the dialog handle the action.  This is the MVVM version of the [Kendo dialog](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dialog/mvvm).

**HTML**

```
<div id="logout_dialog" data-role="dialog" data-title="Logout Confirmation" data-closable="false"
    data-content="Are you sure you want to logout?"
    data-actions="[{ text: 'Yes', action: logout_dialog_yes, primary: true },
    {text:'No', action: close_dialog}]" data-visible="false">
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var logout_dialog = $("#logout_dialog").data("kendoDialog");

logout_dialog.open();

function logout_dialog_yes() {
    APP.models.main_splitter_header.logout_click_yes();
    return;
}

function close_dialog() {
    return true;
}
```